# Julia: What is undef in Array in Julia

Tags: julia

1. This is a constructor for arrays:

`Array{T}(undef, dims)`

I am new to Julia, and don't have a good background in programming. In this syntax, why is `undef` used for creating the array?

2. What is a constructor in Julia, in what situation do we use a constructor?

If we don't type constructor, Julia will automatically create a constructor. Then, Why we use constructor?

Comment: Why isn't the answer by @thomas-jalabert not accepted?

Answer (score 18):

First, you want to understand what is a constructor:
For that, I suggest you the Julia doc: [Constructors in Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#)

Now that you have the theory, let's break apart this expression:

```
a = Array{Int}(undef, (2, 2))
```

What this expression is saying is "I want `a` to be an `Array` of dimension (2, 2)". So Julia will ask for some memory space. When I write it on the Julia REPL:

```
julia> a = Array{Int}(undef, (2, 2))
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0
 0  0
```

Now `Array{T}(undef, dims)` is the generalization of that. "Construct an array of a specific type `T` with a specific number of dimensions `dims`"

So far, I didn't explain what is `undef`. `undef` is a shortcut for `UndefInitializer()`. In this example, we wanted an uninitialized array. What does it mean? For that, you have to understand that variables are not created *ex nihilo* on your terminal. They are occupying a specific place in the memory of your computer. And sometimes, the same memory space was occupied by another variable. So the space my new variable can take might not be empty:

```
julia> a = Array{Float64}(undef, (2, 2))
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 6.94339e-310  6.94339e-310
 6.94339e-310  0.0
```

Here, I never asked for these values to be there. I could erase it to work with a clean variable. But that would mean to erase the value for each cell, and it's much more expensive for the computer to replace each value rather than declaring "here is the new variable".

So basically, `undef` and uninitialized arrays are used for performance purposes. If you want an array well initialized, you can use **[fill](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.fill)**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: How to initialize my array?

Comment: can i avoid undef with anything except nothing?

Comment: As I said in the last sentence of my answer, you can use fill()

Comment: The explanation for seemingly random values in the uninitialized arrays is fascinating. What determines the memory addresses that the newly initialized array may use?

Comment: @AlexTen There are multiples strategies to remplace memory but none of them is perfect, which makes the topic diverse and interesting. One of the most popular strategy is [LRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm#Least_recently_used) (least recently used)